How to make URL link Clickable in Mapviewer popup?
I am trying to make a URL clickable in my mapviewer within AGOL. Currently the links live in the attribute table of my layer named link, and are clickable when looking at the attributes in ArcGIS pro.  I set up the expression for the body of the pop up as shown below.
Tentative Start Date: {Start_Date}
Tentative End Date: {End_Date}
Project Website: {Link}

So the URL shows up in the pop up, but its just text and can't be clicked by the user.  to access the link they need to copy and paste it into the browser.  Does anyone know if this is a simple fix?  I wasn't able to find much online.

Here's how I do it (there may be other ways).  The two important items are in bold...

In AGOL, select the layer, then select the 'Pop-Ups' editor for that layer
Add a 'Text' item to the pop-up
Edit the 'Text' item to include all the text you want including field titles/values
Switch the 'Text' item's editor into 'Source' (HTML) mode (fourth button along in the controls strip along the top of the editor)
Edit the text to include the required HTML <a href=""> and </a> tags to turn the field value into a link (see examples below)
Click the 'OK' button in the 'Text' item's editor
Save the AGOL map

Here are a couple of examples of HTML pop-up text (based on your own use case from your question post):
Project Website: <a href="{Link}">CLICK HERE</a>

Or:
<a href="{Link}">PROJECT WEBSITE</a>

Everything between the <a href=""> and the </a> will be displayed as a clickable link.  The text between the "" is the URL that the click will navigate to.

Another way is to use the Arcade element. You code (which also uses template literals) would look like this:
var output = `Tentative Start Date: ${$feature.Start_Date}<br>
Tentative End Date: ${$feature.End_Date}<br>
<a href="${$feature.Link}">Project Website</a>`

return { 
    type : 'text', 
    text : output
}

